# How to split entry of table data between two forms on two separate pages?

Tags: forms, sinatra

I'm building a simple app in Sinatra that has a single table with 40 properties. I'd like to have the user enter 15 of those properties on one page, click a "Continue" button, and finish entering the other 25 on the next page. Any ideas on the most effective way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

#### #1

Store the form details in a cookie. Not a good choice if the information is sensitive.

#### #2a

Partial submission. Depending on how your storage is set up, you could make the "Continue" a form submission too. This could be done (if it's a database) either with a "temporary" table specially for the partial submissions, or with null fields (not the #1 choice for a database developer) or with different tables. Or perhaps use something like Redis in the middle to store partial submissions.

#### #2b

Asynchronous submission. You could use AJAX to submit fields as they're done. Again, you'd need to store this somehow.

#### #3

On "Continue" store the previous form fields in hidden fields on the next page. Again, not good for sensitive information, and generally this is finickity. I'd avoid this altogether.

There may be more, these are the ones I can think of right now.